# $nearSphere returns too many data

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I noticed that $near and $nearSphere returns completely different data and I got suspicious. After all, when latitude is near equator it sphere distance shouldn't differ a lot from euclidean distance.

```
db.tablebusiness.find({ "LongitudeLatitude" : { "$nearSphere" : [106.772835, -6.186753], "$maxDistance" : 0.053980478460939611 }, "Prominent" : { "$gte" : 15 }, "indexContents" : { "$all" : [/^soto/, /^nasi/] } }).limit(200);
```

It returns 48 data.

I'll attached it anyway

```
/* 0 */
{
  "_id" : "nasi-uduk-soto-ayam__-6.18_106.77",
  "BuildingID" : null,
  "Title" : "Nasi Uduk Soto Ayam",
  "InBuildingAddress" : null,
  "Building" : null,
  "Street" : "Jl. Panjang",
  "Districts" : [],
  "City" : "Jakarta",
  "Country" : "Indonesia",
  "LongitudeLatitudeFromGoogle" : null,
  "DistanceFromGoogleAddress" : 0.0,
  "Checkin" : 0,
  "Note" : null,
  "PeopleCount" : 0,
  "Prominent" : 45.5,
  "CountViews" : 0,
  "StreetAdditional" : null,
  "LongitudeLatitude" : {
    "Longitude" : 106.765673160553,
    "Latitude" : -6.17522230915668
  },
  "Rating" : {
    "Stars" : 0.0,
    "Weight" : 0.0
  },
  "CurrentlyWorkedURL" : null,
  "Reviews" : [],
  "ZIP" : null,
  "Tags" : ["Restaurant"],
  "Phones" : [],
  "Website" : null,
  "Email" : null,
  "Price" : null,
  "openingHour" : null,
  "Promotions" : [],
  "SomethingWrong" : false,
  "BizMenus" : [],
  "Brochures" : [],
  "Aliases" : [],
  "indexContents" : ["restaura", "estauran", "staurant", "taurant", "aurant", "urant", "rant", "ant", "nt", "t", "nasi", "asi", "si", "i", "uduk", "duk", "uk", "k", "soto", "oto", "to", "o", "ayam", "yam", "am", "m"]
}

/* 1 */
{
  "_id" : "nasi-soto-padang_pasar-slipi-jaya_-6.19_106.80",
  "BuildingID" : null,
  "Title" : "Nasi Soto Padang",
  "InBuildingAddress" : "Lt.1 Los Alas",
  "Building" : null,
  "Street" : "Jl.Kemanggisan Utama Raya",
  "Districts" : [],
  "City" : "Jakarta",
  "Country" : "Indonesia",
  "LongitudeLatitudeFromGoogle" : null,
  "DistanceFromGoogleAddress" : 0.0,
  "Checkin" : 0,
  "Note" : null,
  "PeopleCount" : 0,
  "Prominent" : 45.5,
  "CountViews" : 0,
  "StreetAdditional" : null,
  "LongitudeLatitude" : {
    "Longitude" : 106.79647564888,
    "Latitude" : -6.18998465381734
  },
  "Rating" : {
    "Stars" : 0.0,
    "Weight" : 0.0
  },
  "CurrentlyWorkedURL" : null,
  "Reviews" : [],
  "ZIP" : null,
  "Tags" : ["Restaurant"],
  "Phones" : [],
  "Website" : null,
  "Email" : null,
  "Price" : null,
  "openingHour" : null,
  "Promotions" : [],
  "SomethingWrong" : false,
  "BizMenus" : [],
  "Brochures" : [],
  "Aliases" : [],
  "indexContents" : ["restaura", "estauran", "staurant", "taurant", "aurant", "urant", "rant", "ant", "nt", "t", "nasi", "asi", "si", "i", "soto", "oto", "to", "o", "padang", "adang", "dang", "ang", "ng", "g"]
}
```

...

```
/* 47 */
{
  "_id" : "nasi-gandul__-7.43_109.24",
  "BuildingID" : null,
  "Title" : "Nasi Gandul",
  "InBuildingAddress" : null,
  "Building" : null,
  "Street" : "Jl. Brobahan Pr - 40 rt 004 Rw 004",
  "Districts" : [],
  "City" : "Purwokerto",
  "Country" : "Indonesia",
  "LongitudeLatitudeFromGoogle" : null,
  "DistanceFromGoogleAddress" : 0.0,
  "Checkin" : 0,
  "Note" : null,
  "PeopleCount" : 0,
  "Prominent" : 30.5,
  "CountViews" : 0,
  "StreetAdditional" : null,
  "LongitudeLatitude" : {
    "Longitude" : 109.239182174206,
    "Latitude" : -7.42585664273589
  },
  "Rating" : {
    "Stars" : 3.0,
    "Weight" : 1.0
  },
  "CurrentlyWorkedURL" : null,
  "Reviews" : [],
  "ZIP" : "53116",
  "Tags" : ["Angkringan", "Restaurant Indonesian", "Soto & Sop"],
  "Phones" : ["+62(281)7918181"],
  "Website" : null,
  "Email" : null,
  "Price" : null,
  "openingHour" : null,
  "Promotions" : [],
  "SomethingWrong" : false,
  "BizMenus" : [],
  "Brochures" : [],
  "Aliases" : [],
  "indexContents" : ["angkring", "ngkringa", "gkringan", "kringan", "ringan", "ingan", "ngan", "gan", "an", "n", "restaura", "estauran", "staurant", "taurant", "aurant", "urant", "rant", "ant", "nt", "t", "indonesi", "ndonesia", "donesian", "onesian", "nesian", "esian", "sian", "ian", "soto", "oto", "to", "o", "&", "sop", "op", "p", "nasi", "asi", "si", "i", "gandul", "andul", "ndul", "dul", "ul", "l"]
}
```

I put the data into excel and compute the distance using this formula

=SQRT(POWER(E2-$G$1,2)+POWER((F2-$H$1)*COS($H$1*PI()/180),2))

That one should greatly approximate spherical distance. Also notice that latitude is -6 which is not far from equator.

Here is the result

```
0.013516826
0.023857967
0.037658667
0.038737146
0.042414787
0.046725248
0.051006427
0.053567221
0.057448344
0.061592999
0.062329244
0.065276161
0.066035611
0.076251787
0.109671831
0.112097201
0.13417281
0.136471939
0.172293693
1.058802838
1.078123028
1.079160684
1.080954023
1.081148114
1.081099449
1.092061283
1.094281476
1.094431917
1.096845722
1.097063729
1.096953691
1.097201996
1.105389179
1.105442127
1.10839237
1.108717834
1.108840349
1.111636423
1.113187903
1.118767984
1.118767984
1.133952371
1.135077548
1.154967917
1.161142923
1.185994885
1.199509086
2.756884824
```

Here is the screenshot of my excel sheet[image]

Here is the actual excel

```
            106.772835  -6.186753
  "_id"      "nasi-uduk-soto-ayam__-6.18_106.77",   106.7656732 -6.175222309    0.013516826
  "_id"      "nasi-soto-padang_pasar-slipi-jaya_-6.19_106.80",  106.7964756 -6.189984654    0.023857967
  "_id"      "nasi-uduk-soto-ayam__-6.22_106.77",   106.7718959 -6.224620499    0.037658667
  "_id"      "nasi-campur-%26-soto-babat-kenanga_komp.-ruko-permata-senayan%2C_-6.22_106.79",   106.79199   -6.22062    0.038737146
  "_id"      "soto-mie-nasi_indomaret-(univ.-mercu-buana)_-6.21_106.74",    106.7379928 -6.211082144    0.042414787
  "_id"      "soto-kudus%2C-soto-ayam-%26amp%3B-nasi-pindang_plaza-senayan_-6.23_106.80",   106.7989969 -6.225694167    0.046725248
  "_id"      "soto-kudus%2C-soto-ayam-%26amp%3B-nasi-pindang_plaza-bri-ii_-6.22_106.81",    106.8136847 -6.217476287    0.051006427
  "_id"      "soto-kudus%2C-soto-ayam-%26amp%3B-nasi-pindang_automall-indonesia_-6.23_106.81",  106.8096431 -6.225898946    0.053567221
  "_id"      "soto-kudus%2C-soto-ayam-%26amp%3B-nasi-pindang_menara-mulia_-6.22_106.82",    106.81656   -6.224232983    0.057448344
  "_id"      "nasi-gule-gandaria__-6.24_106.80",    106.795285  -6.244444863    0.061592999
  "_id"      "nasi-soto-monggo-mampir__-6.24_106.80",   106.7971516 -6.244479441    0.062329244
  "_id"      "nasi-soto-ayam-\"pak-min\"__-6.24_106.82",    106.8151546 -6.236743573    0.065276161
  "_id"      "nasi-soto-ayam-pak-min---santa__-6.24_106.81",    106.812959  -6.239508   0.066035611
  "_id"      "soto-mie-nasi-bogor__-6.23_106.83",   106.8322349 -6.234845139    0.076251787
  "_id"      "nasi-uduk-soto-ayam__-6.24_106.87",   106.8693781 -6.239089942    0.109671831
  "_id"      "soto-ayam-%2F-nasi-uduk-betawi__-6.28_106.71",    106.714092  -6.282785   0.112097201
  "_id"      "soto-minang-roda-jaya_ruko-tongkol-indah_-6.12_106.89",   106.889044  -6.119294471    0.13417281
  "_id"      "nasi-bebek-dan-soto-mas-muchlis_summarecon-kelapa-gading_-6.16_106.91",   106.9059021 -6.156281135    0.136471939
  "_id"      "nasi-liwet-%26-soto-kwali-kalimalang__-6.25_106.93",  106.9338112 -6.248527508    0.172293693
  "_id"      "soto-ayam-nasi-rames__-6.88_107.58",  107.5751638 -6.881692483    1.058802838
  "_id"      "nasi-liwet-soto-solo_rumah-mode_-6.88_107.60",    107.5998616 -6.882452292    1.078123028
  "_id"      "nasi-soto-ayam-madura__-6.91_107.57", 107.5749707 -6.912900474    1.079160684
  "_id"      "nasi-soto-mie__-6.89_107.60", 107.5969434 -6.890355658    1.080954023
  "_id"      "nasi-rames-soto-bandung-enjoi__-6.89_107.60", 107.5970721 -6.890504777    1.081148114
  "_id"      "nasi-soto-ayam__-6.91_107.58",    107.5769877 -6.913560825    1.081099449
  "_id"      "nasi-soto-ayam__-6.91_107.60",    107.5977552 -6.90656    1.092061283
  "_id"      "nasi-soto-ayam-madura__-6.89_107.62", 107.6157832 -6.888615935    1.094281476
  "_id"      "nasi-goreng-soto-ayam__-6.90_107.61", 107.6093245 -6.89662571 1.094431917
  "_id"      "nasi-soto-gulai-kambing__-6.90_107.61",   107.6090455 -6.900715755    1.096845722
  "_id"      "putra-bengawan-nasi-goreng-%26-soto__-6.89_107.62",   107.617187  -6.891298   1.097063729
  "_id"      "nasi-soto-ayam__-6.90_107.61",    107.6088095 -6.901163102    1.096953691
  "_id"      "nasi-uduk-%26amp%3B-soto-kikil-cak-khohar__-6.89_107.61", 107.6144958 -6.894765295    1.097201996
  "_id"      "nasi-soto-ayam__-6.90_107.62",    107.6204395 -6.900453028    1.105389179
  "_id"      "nasi-goreng-soto-ayam__-6.90_107.62", 107.6206326 -6.900303912    1.105442127
  "_id"      "nasi-soto-ayam-madura__-6.91_107.62", 107.6169634 -6.909279174    1.10839237
  "_id"      "nasi-soto_pasar-baru_-6.92_107.61",   107.605226  -6.923423387    1.108717834
  "_id"      "nasi-soto-ayam-madura_pasar-baru_-6.92_107.61",   107.6053333 -6.92348729 1.108840349
  "_id"      "nasi-soto-sarinah__-6.90_107.63", 107.631175  -6.897282   1.111636423
  "_id"      "nasi-uduk-soto__-6.89_107.64",    107.6361465 -6.893636262    1.113187903
  "_id"      "nasi-soto-ayam-madura__-6.91_107.63", 107.629376  -6.910677   1.118767984
  "_id"      "nasi-soto-ayam__-6.91_107.63",    107.629376  -6.910677   1.118767984
  "_id"      "nasi-uduk-soto__-6.94_107.62",    107.6248813 -6.93937772 1.133952371
  "_id"      "nasi-soto-ayam-khas-madura__-6.94_107.63",    107.625749  -6.940099   1.135077548
  "_id"      "nasi-uduk-%26amp%3B-soto__-6.96_107.64",  107.638936  -6.955310213    1.154967917
  "_id"      "nasi-soto-ayam_ruko-metro-trade-center_-6.94_107.66", 107.6600504 -6.940208438    1.161142923
  "_id"      "nasi-soto-ayam-khas-madura__-6.94_107.69",    107.6948118 -6.937141164    1.185994885
  "_id"      "nasi-soto-ayam-khas-madura-cak-nonk__-6.93_107.72",   107.7156472 -6.932668019    1.199509086
  "_id"      "nasi-gandul__-7.43_109.24",   109.2391822 -7.425856643    2.756884824
```

Look again the term in the query

```
"$maxDistance" : 0.053980478460939611
```

Go figure.

By the way $maxDistance is DEFINETLY used properly. Reducing it does lead to less results. The issue seems to come from the fact that whatever formula mongodb use to compute distance is inaccurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered the same post you made on stackexchange: 
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23869/nearsphere-returns-too-many-data-what-am-i-missing-am-i-wrong-is-it-a-bug-d

Does that help?

Thanks,
andrew

Comment: Partially. I was greatly surprised that $maxDistance is in radian for $nearSphere.

Comment: So, the long lat is in degree. If we use $near, we also specify $maxDistance in the same dimension we specify longlat. Yet out of nowhere, the $maxDistance is in radian.